# Send command "next slide" to PowerPoint slideshow C#

Tags: c#, winforms, powerpoint

I'm writing a desktop application using **C#** in **.NET Framework**, windows forms. I want to send a signal(next slide) from my app to a **PowerPoint** slideshow.
can someone guide me how to?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/view-gotoslide-method-powerpoint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - way to programmatically advance Powerpoint slide show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463358/c-sharp-way-to-programmatically-advance-powerpoint-slide-show)

Comment: thanks! was helpfull